# Notification: 'Add a device Tap to set up your iPhone' - I don't have an iPhone

Tags: windows-10, security

Hope I can get some advice - I received a system notification: 'Add a device Tap to set up your iPhone' or 'finish setting up your iPhone' or similar (notification disappeared before I could take a screenshot).

... but no one in my household has an iPhone. It's a Windows 10 desktop - it's on my desk, ethernet connection, no wifi, bluetooth on (not permanently discoverable) in a suburban low density setting - i.e. no one could have plugged anything in without me noticing, no one else was around at the time, and I'm on a straightforward non-managed network. Win10 is updated, running a common AV/security program.

There's nothing I don't recognise in the "Bluetooth and other devices" Windows settings pane, and nothing in device manager that catches my eye.

I did not click the notification. Should I do anything to follow-up? Is there somewhere I can see what devices are connected to my PC/a log of connection attempts?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps someone has some Apple device, even earpods? Clicking on the notification might be the best way to find the issuing program.

Comment: A screenshot or even photo might be really helpful. tbh, if something is legitimately expecting you to add an iPhone, the notification would probably hang around longer.